# Access Modifiers in Java when used with Immutable Class

Tags: java, immutability

Is it recommended to have public access modifiers for the data fields in final (Immutable) java class, even if the data fields are not the references to mutable datatype Or Shall we access data fields directly as data fields are supposed to be defined in constructor itself hence nullify all chances of changing the internal representation of class.
Please suggest?

For example:

```
public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Immutablesample immutablesample = Immutablesample.getInstance("akkhil");

        System.out.println(" Before modification " + immutablesample.getName());
        immutablesample.name = "gupta";
        System.out.println(" After modification " + immutablesample.getName());
    }

}
```

is the calling code trying to change the data field by accessing it directly(without access modifier) for the following class:

```
public final class Immutablesample {


    private final String name;

    private Immutablesample(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public static Immutablesample getInstance(String name){
        return new Immutablesample(name);
    }
}
```

How would it make the class prone to get its internal representation changed if i change the modifier from private to public 
private String name; to public String name;
since the object was creating with parameterized constructor so has immutable data fields, than why is it necessary to make data fields private?

Comment: Can you post an example or two? Your lack in use of punctuation and proper terminology makes it hard to understand the question.

Comment: you can find all details here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html

Comment: No. Data fields should always be private and final. Provide only getters (which can return defensive copies of mutable instances if needed)

Comment: Are you asking if it's ok to make an immutable `final` field `public`? If so, yes, that's OK as far as immutability goes, but as @GhostCat points out there are other problems with exposing fields outside the declaring class.

Comment: Following is the code snippet:

Comment: Thanks for the quick accept/feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two simple rules to follow:

1. Try to make your whole class as "immutable" as you can. For example setting *private final* fields only via constructors. And when using "incoming" collection objects, consider to create a **copy** of their content to be really on the safe side.
2. Keep in mind that good OO is about exposing **behavior**; not about exposing **data**. Meaning: you absolutely do **not** want to make fields public unless you have really good reasons to do so. In other words: you do **not** want that some other class B does something because of the content of some field in class A. And the way to prevent that: making your fields private!

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's a bad decision to show your inner presentation of a class, so it's much better if you hide even final immutable fields. You can only show such as fields if your class it's something like a tuple, where all members are used from outside.